'notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(Int, Int): Unit' and 'setRemoteAdapter(Int, Intent!): Unit' are deprecated
As the title says,
'notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(Int, Int): Unit' and 'setRemoteAdapter(Int, Intent!): Unit' are now deprecated
I use those functions to manage the widgets of my app, but they are now deprected (I'm using API 35). How can I replace them?

FYI, that seems to be covered in the documentation.

yep, but I'm not being able to migrate my code, I don't understand how to create the RemoteCollectionItems

If you look https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections#use-remote-collections here, there's no example on how to pass a list of objects. I have 300+ entries to show in the widget, and this method simply doesn't work for this use case.

It seems like calling addItem() in a loop should work for 300+ entries.

I'll try, but in my case, this doesn't simplify the app. Also, my items contain bitmaps :(

Then perhaps have fewer discrete items in your collection. Or stick with the deprecated methods until better alternatives are added in future years.
